# The 'flag' appears only when the first turtle touches the finish line

Tags: python, pygame

[[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QUW5.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/694bC.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jiZh.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OG6D7.png)

The 'flag' which called 'win' appears only when the first turtle touches the finish line. Let's say when the 2nd turtle win, It still doesn't count it as a win, it waits for 1st turtle to touch the finish line. I tried fixing It, but I could't do that. So, If the 1st turtle touches the finish line, the 'flag' which is called 'win' should appear in front of the 1st turtle. And same for 2nd and 3rd turtles. But even if 2nd or 3rd turtle win, still the programe ends when the 1st turtle touches the finish line. I will be so gratefull if you help me. If you didn't understand something, you can write me and can explain it to you!

```
import pygame
from random import randint

pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
sc = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 350))
pl = pygame.image.load('pl.png')
t = pygame.image.load('tr.png')
win = pygame.image.load('win.png')
finish = pygame.image.load('finish.png')
r_f = pygame.Rect(360, 60, 60, 60)
x1 = x2 = x3 = 0
winner = 0

while winner == 0:
    sc.blit(pl, (0, 0))
    sc.blit(finish, r_f)

    r_t1 = pygame.Rect(x1, 64, 60, 60)
    r_t2 = pygame.Rect(x2, 160, 60, 60)
    r_t3 = pygame.Rect(x3, 240, 60, 60)

    sc.blit(t, r_t1)
    sc.blit(t, r_t2)
    sc.blit(t, r_t3)

    x1 = x1 + randint(0,3)
    x2 = x2 + randint(0,3)
    x3 = x3 + randint(0,3)
    
    if r_t1.colliderect(r_f):
        winner = 1
        sc.blit(win, (300, 20))
    if r_t2.colliderect(r_f):
        winner = 1
        sc.blit(win, (300, 100))
    if r_t3.colliderect(r_f):
        winner = 1
        sc.blit(win, (300, 200))

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

I tried fixing It, but I could't do that. So, If the 1st turtle touches the finish line, the 'flag' which is called 'win' should appear in front of the 1st turtle. And same for 2nd and 3rd turtles. But even if 2nd or 3rd turtle win, still the programe ends when the 1st turtle touches the finish line.

Comment: As soon as any turtle collides you set `winner` to 1 and the while loop ends. You need to separate this logic if you want to keep tracking turtle collisions.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your defined area for `r_f`.  You only made the finish line area 60 pixels tall, so only r_t1 can ever collide with it.

Try changing the rectangle for `r_f` to something like:

```
r_f = pygame.Rect(360, 54, 10, 200)
```

You can also use the size of the .png image to programmatically set it's position and the rectangle size as follows:

```
finish = pygame.image.load('finish.png')
finish_w, finish_h = finish.get_size()
r_f = pygame.Rect(360, (350 - finish_h)//2, finish_w, finish_h)
```

or if you want to manually adjust the y position, you could just use:

```
r_f = pygame.Rect(360, 54, *finish.get_size())
```

Comment: It actually makes more sense to do this `pygame.Rect(360, 60, *finish.get_size())`. The graphic is actually 242px tall. Also, this does not solve all of the problems. Ramin claims it works, but the loop is still going to end as soon as the first turtle crosses the line.

Comment: @OysterShucker It's SUPPOSED to end as soon as the first turtle crosses the line.  The problem before was that ONLY turtle 1 could trigger the winner flag.  If you set turtles 2 and 3 to go much faster, they would just run right out of the game without the race ending because they would never collide with `r_f`.  However, your point about using `get_size()` is valid, with the possible exception of possibly wanting the collision rectangle to not exactly match the png image size - for example if you moved the x position right a bit and made it thinner.

Comment: I remade their game where all turtles get to the line, and their position is imposed on the flag. Then a 3 second wait and a new race. I've never seen a race in my entire life that completely ended the instant the first thing crossed the finish line.

Comment: @OysterShucker  That's not the problem OP was having.  If he wants to change that,  then that has to do with loop control variable and needs other changes such as making the turtles stop once they reach the finish.
 The question was how to make it so that turtle2 and turtle3 get the winner flag appropriately assigned when they win the race.  Anything beyond that is an additional question and should get an additional post, as per standard SO protocols.

Comment: get size is a bad choice because it relies upon the shape of the image.  What is the image is too short?

Comment: @UpAndAdam That's why my first suggestion just used constant int values.  I also would consider using a narrower width so the contact point can be at a particular point within the image if desired. There is a presumption that if the image for the finish line is too small, it should be replaced by an image that is the correct size.

Comment: thats also why i upvoted your answer, but you focused on using an image's size in your code. so i elaborated off of that. relying on an image is a brittle proposition and isnt a responsive design for changes later.  reading the code you can't tell if it should hit or not.

Comment: @UpAndAdam I only added the image size option at OysterShucker's  suggestion.  I had actually run the code with the OPs images, so I could verify it would work

Comment: veryfying it works with todays image doesnt advance your point at all and only shows that you don't get it.  what about when the image changes?  It shouldn't require visually testing it. that leads to human error and bugs.   If you base the target region off of a defined region based on the participating sprites you can never be wrong.

Comment: @UpAndAdam Which is exactly why my original answer used a defined region. What are you not getting?  Both solutions given work for the program provided by the OP.  Obviously, if you have a completely different program, with completely different sprites, and they all have different areas and different regions, the collisions areas are going to be different.   The key problem with the original program is that the original region used by the OP was only 60 pixels tall. That problem has been solved.

Answer (score -1):

All the comments were missing the problem.  The other answer nails the problem but I disagree on one aspect of the solution where the focus in on using the image's geometry. ( and hadn't seen it when I made my post)

The problem is the shape of and placement of `r_f`.  It's y coordinate is `60`, its width and height are both `60`.

So only the first `turtle` can ever collide with it because the `turtle`s are only moving along the X axis and exist at different spots on the Y axis.  The way in which you are moving no other turtle can ever collide with `r_f` because of the y value and height.

I dont know which direction rectangles height and widths expand in `pygame` framework, but you need to make it such that the height of `r_f` and Y position of `r_f` is such that it extends from roughly y of `64` to y of `300` so that all the objects will be able to collide with it properly. (I'm not familiar with it but I assume the x,y is the lower right hand coordinate of the rectangle, and length and width extend positively rightward and upward )

Using an image for a size is a recipe for failure if your image isn't sized properly.   It is significantly safer to make sure all the objects can potentially collide, by using min and max functionality to calculate the min and max Y values that the target needs to be for a collision to occur.  In this way, no matter how many 'turtle's you add regardless of the image of the goal, they will all be able to win.

Also note that since OP is checking every frame, and only moving by '1-3' units X and the goal width is 60 that none of the 'wins' will be missed.   However in a situation like this you don't really need a collision check, you really only need to check the rightmost X value of each object to see if it crossed the line or not....

But you are also not handling a tie properly. In your program is it not literally possible for two turtles to cross the line at the same time?

Comment: Thank you! Your answer really helped me. I'm sorry, I'm new at turtle and I didn't know much about r_f. I didn't know which coordinates I should use, that's why my code didn't run correctly. And I don't know If it's possible for 2 of them to cross the finish line at the same time. It was my homework and I'm a 9th grader. So I think even If they can cross the finish line at the same time, the teacher still would accept It because there were some hints about what I need to use in this code, and in there It said that I should use (0,3).

Comment: none of that has anything to do with what i said. new at turtle?  you mean new at python? i'm not saying theres anythign wrong with using 0,3. if they finish at the same time its a tie. if my answer helped please upvote

Comment: it doesn't matter whether its homework or a self created project, the goal is to learn the language and the framework. the goal is not to simply make a homework assignment work or you have learned nothing, and the assignment has no meaning. the most important thing is the why.   If you dont understand what you are doing you need to ask more questions in your class and here.